# How to filter a custom ListAdapter in android?

Tags: java, android

I have searched a lot, but no any solutions are working for me. I am seting a custom arrayadapter which has a imageview and a textview. I kept an edittext where i want to add text and i wish to get the list filtered by these given texts, When i use a string type array adapter this works great, but its not working in my custom adapter, here is my code:

```
public class CurrenciesFrom extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ListView lvCurrencies;
    String[] countryCode = { "BDT Bangladesh","BBF bafa" ,"USD America", "UMK Umaka","KRW Korea",
            "INR India" };
    int[] flag = { R.drawable.bdt, R.drawable.usd, R.drawable.aud,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher ,R.drawable.usd, R.drawable.aud};
    ArrayAdapter<Currency> adapter;
    List<Currency> l;
    EditText etsearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.currencies);
        initializer();
        lvCurrencies.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvCurrencies.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        etsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                CurrenciesFrom.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private List<Currency> getModel() {
        List<Currency> list = new ArrayList<Currency>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countryCode.length; i++) {

            list.add(get(countryCode[i], flag[i]));
        }

        list.get(1).setSelected(true); // select one item by default
        return list;
    }

    private Currency get(String s, int place) {
        return new Currency(s, place);
    }

    private void initializer() {

        lvCurrencies = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCurrencies);
        etsearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        lvCurrencies.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // countryCode = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Currencies);
        l = getModel();

        Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Currency>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Currency c1, Currency c2) {
                return c1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getName());
            }
        });

        adapter = new Customarrayadapter(this, l);
    }
```

My custom adapter class is:

```
package com.powergroupbd.yahoo;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Customarrayadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Currency> {

    private final List<Currency> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public Customarrayadapter(Activity context, List<Currency> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.showlist, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected ImageView sub;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.showlist, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            viewHolder.sub = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sub);

            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            Currency element = (Currency) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                            System.out.println("Checked : " + element.getName());
                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.sub.setImageResource(list.get(position).getPlace());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User this code, for filter the text

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
int before, int count)
{

    textlength = edittext.getText().length();
    text_sort.clear();
    image_sort.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        if (textlength <= text[i].length())
        {
            if (edittext.getText().toString().
                    equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
            {
                text_sort.add(text[i]);
                image_sort.add(image[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, image_sort));

    }
}
```

for more, refer this site it may help you http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-search-in-custom-listview.html

Comment: What is the text_sort, image_sort and text here? please explain

Comment: @Reyjohn: text_sort and image_sort are the filtered text and image respectively, for more info  Refer that link man

Comment: you link thaseems to be helpful, its my fault that i cant use it in my ways

Comment: my customadapter class is in another java file, so i cant linkup with some variables that you did likr text.size in both classes, so i couldnt use this

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is very misleading and ignores the actual problem. The OP is incorrectly subclassing `ArrayAdapter`. You should never track your own list of data and instead access that data through the proper adapter methods. Eg, `getItem(position)`.  The `ArrayAdapter` makes no guarentees that the `List` instance you pass into it stays the same.

In fact, during a filter operation, it copies the data over to a new `ArrayList` instance. That means your list used in the subclass is no longer referring to the same list in the `ArrayAdapter`.  Since you are accessing your own list in the `getView()` method; instead of pulling from `getItem()`, any filtering changes will be missed. In fact by this point, you also broke the ability to add or remove from the adapter as well.

Most important rule when subclassing `ArrayAdapter`. Never keep an external list of data. Always refer into the `ArrayAdapter` instead.